# Is there a more efficient way to set a std::vector from a stream?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector, stringstream, ostringstream

Presently, I set the value of a `std::vector<char>` from an `std::ostringstream` as follows:

```
void
foo(std::vector<char> &data, std::stringstream &stream) {
  data = std::vector<char>(stream.str().begin(), stream.str().end());
}
```

I'm wondering if there is a more efficient way to do this with STL in C++ or whether the method I give here is considered appropriate?  Would I be better off using `std::stringstream` instead?

Comment: I'm not sure how efficient that is, but it *is* incorrect. The two calls to `.str()` return different objects.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that error, thought I was getting a reference not a copy from str().

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your method invokes *undefined behaviour*. `stream.str()` returns a string *by-value*, aka a temporary string. You take the `begin` iterator of one temporary and the `end` iterator of the other, creating an invalid range.

One method to convert a stream to a container is to use the common iterator interface:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(){
  std::stringstream src("....");
  std::vector<char> dest;
  // for a bit of efficiency
  std::streampos beg = src.tellg();
  src.seekg(0, std::ios_base::end);
  std::streampos end = src.tellg();
  src.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg);
  dest.reserve(end - beg);

  dest.assign(std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(src), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

  std::copy(dest.begin(), dest.end(), std::ostream_iterator<char>(std::cout));
}
```

[Live example on Ideone.](http://ideone.com/ptBBD)

Another method would be to cache the returned `std::string` object:

```
std::string const& s = stream.str();
data.reserve(s.size());
data.assign(s.begin(), s.end());
```

Comment: Why are there two std::copy() calls?  They seem redundant to me.

Comment: @WilliamKF: The first (now replaced by `.assign`) was to insert into the vector, the second outputs to `std::cout` (too lazy for a handwritten loop).

Comment: I suppose it's too much to hope that `src.rdbuf()->in_avail()` gives the correct size without messing around with `seek`? I'm not good with the stream libraries.

Comment: @Steve: You're better than me, it seems, since I didn't even remember that function until now. No idea if it will work the same, though.

Answer (score 12):

As pointed out in comments, your code is incorrect due to the two calls to `str()`. In order to improve efficiency you can avoid creating a temporary `vector`, like this:

```
void foo(std::vector<char> &data, std::stringstream &stream) {
    const std::string& str = stream.str();
    data.assign( str.begin(), str.end() );
}
```

You can also avoid the `std::string` by using `std::istreambuf_iterator`s:

```
void foo(std::vector<char> &data, std::stringstream &stream) {
    data.assign(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>( stream ), std::istreambuf_iterator<char>()
    );
}
```

but given that those are *input iterators*, the `vector` has no chance to know how much data will be assigned and could perform a bit worse, as it cannot `reserve` enough space to avoid reallocations.

Comment: I think you would probably want `istreambuf_iterator` here rather than `istream_iterator`, otherwise you'll lose whitespace.

Comment: Yes, aside from not specifying the character type. :-]

Comment: @ildjarn: Is it needed? The reference I'm checking says it defaults to `char`. Indeed, is needed. Seems like a quirk in that particular reference.

Comment: §24.6.3 says the signature is `template<class charT, class traits = char_traits<charT> > class istreambuf_iterator`, no default.

Comment: You can obtain the correct size to `reserve` through `seekg` and `tellg` on the `std::stringstream`, see my answer.

Comment: Oh btw, `istreambuf_iterator`s are constructible from streams, no need for the call to `rdbuf`. :)

Answer (score 4):

Copy from a stream iterator to a back insert iterator:

```
std::istream src;
std::vector<char> dst;

std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(src), std::istream_iterator<char>(), std::back_inserter(dst));
```

The istream_iterator uses formatted conversion (i.e. skips whitespace), so this may not be what you want. I'm not sure what your goal is.

Answer (score 0):

> if there is a more efficient way

You may want to call `reserve` on your `data` and use the range `insert` member directly on `data` instead of using a copy-assignment. The thing about `vector`s that you need to remember is that every node may potentially increase the size (and relocate all elements). So, you're better off allocating the memory in one go (if you know how many objects you will be storing -- which you do know here) and leverage this fact.

Comment: I actually would assume most implementations will use a [`std::distance`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/distance) call in the iterator-based constructor to do that logic themselves.

Comment: @KillianDS : Likely only for random-access iterators, otherwise the range would be needlessly traversed twice.

Comment: @ildjarm: and necessarily not for input iterators, which cannot be traversed twice.