# Stringstream to Vector<char> throws std::bad_alloc

Tags: c++, vector, stringstream

I was tinkering with Boost Property Tree a bit, and I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2861087/1062484) example. I needed to convert the final result to vector, so I just added one more line after

```
write_json(ss, root);
```

like this:

```
std::vector<char> testVec(std::begin(ss.str()), std::end(ss.str()));
```

I have also tried this instead:

```
std::string someString = ss.str()
char* someArray = (char*)someString.c_str();
std::vector<char> someVec(someArray, someArray+sizeof(someArray));
```

In both the cases, I am getting this error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

Any hints what I am doing wrong? It is not a problem of property tree, I gather. It is a problem of string to vector conversion. I guess this makes sense, because vectors are only supposed to be one dimensional, but I have no clue how to convert that string to vector and get it back again.

Comment: For one thing, `sizeof(someArray)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)` which is definitely *not* what you want.

Comment: You might want to look at  


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823264/is-there-a-more-efficient-way-to-set-a-stdvector-from-a-stream

Answer (score 14):

This fails:

```
std::vector<char> testVec(std::begin(ss.str()), std::end(ss.str()));
```

because the `std::begin()` and `std::end()` are not associated with same `std::string` instance. The [`ss.str()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream/str) returns a new `std::string` instance each time, it does not return a `std::string&` to some internal member.

This is incorrect:

```
std::vector<char> someVec(someArray, someArray+sizeof(someArray));
```

because `sizeof(someArray)` is `sizeof(char*)`. If there is less than `sizeof(char*)` elements in `someArray` an attempt will be made to read memory that should not.

A possible solution:

```
std::string someString = ss.str();
std::vector<char> someVec(someString.begin(), someString.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

`sizeof()` isn't giving you the length of the array, because c strings don't know their length (null-terminated). It's just providing the size of the memory location for the pointer at the beginning of the array, which is why you can reference past the end of the string using operator[] if you're not careful.

Another solution is to overload sizeof to iterate through the string until it hits the null terminator, but that seems like something you could do with built in things without going through the extra work.